# Stop multiple method recursive calls from dependent inputs in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Dear you great people at stack overflow,

I am struggling with using vue.js to control a group of inputs. I want to have one ('Shop' in example below) controlling the options in the other ones. But I also want the same update event to fire regardless of what was changed. My problem is that as I change the main option (again 'Shop' below) I do not know if other inputs will be changed so I do not know whether I have to call the update function or whether this is done indirectly when other options change. The effect is that I may have two update calls which I absolutely do not want. I have spent some time writing a stylized version of what I am trying to do and you can see in the console log that when the 'country' or 'gender' is not set to 'all' and you change 'shop' two updates will fire.

So I'm wondering if anyone has any elegant way of solving this dependence without multiple update calls. As I will be using something similar a lot I am open to changing the whole set up, I'm pretty new to Vue.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id ='app'>
      <div>
        <div style='list-style-type: none' v-for="input in inputs">
          <p><b>{{ input.name }}</b></p>
          <select v-model="input.value">
             <option v-for="option in input.options" :value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
           </select>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>

    </div>
    <script>
      let vueApp = new Vue ({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          inputs: [
            {name: 'shop', value: 'all', options: [{id: 'all', name: 'All shops'}, {id: 1, name: 'Shop 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Shop 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Shop 3'}]},
            {name: 'country', value: 'all', options: [{id: 'all', name: 'All countries'}, {id: 1, name: 'Country 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Country 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Country 3'}]},
            {name: 'gender', value: 'all', options: [{id: 'all', name: 'All genders'}, {id: 1, name: 'Gender 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Gender 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Gender 3'}]}
          ]
        },
        computed: {
          shop() {return this.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'shop')[0].value;},
          nonShop() {return this.inputs.filter(d => d.name !== 'shop').map(d => d.value)}
        },
        watch: {
          shop() {
             $.when((async function() {
                setTimeout(
                  () => {
                    let newCountries = [];
                    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                      let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                      newCountries.push({id: rand, name: 'Country: ' + rand});
                      let countryObject = vueApp.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'country')[0];
                      countryObject.options = [{id: 'all', name: 'All countries'}, ...newCountries];
                      countryObject.value = 'all';
                    }                   
                  }
                , 200);
             })(),
             (async function() {
                setTimeout(
                  () => {
                    let newGenders = [];
                    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                      let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                      newGenders.push({id: rand, name: 'Gender: ' + rand});
                      let genderObject = vueApp.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'gender')[0];
                      genderObject.options = [{id: 'all', name: 'All genders'}, ...newGenders];
                      genderObject.value = 'all';
                    }                   
                  }
                , 100);          
             })()).done(() => this.update());
          },
          nonShop() {this.update()}
        },
        methods: {
          update() {console.log('updating');}
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <strike>Can you clarify what isn't working as expected?</strike> Nevermind, I see now.  [Here's your code in a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kwda0yeh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `update` in the watchers for `shop` and `nonShop`, just add a `change` event handler to the `selects` to call `update` that way instead:

```
<select v-model="input.value" @change="update">...</select>
```

This way, the `update` method will be called whenever the user changes the value of an input, not when the value of an input gets updated by Vue.

Here's a full working example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let vueApp = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{
        name: 'shop', 
        value: 'all', 
        options: [
          {id: 'all', name: 'All shops'}, 
          {id: 1, name: 'Shop 1'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Shop 2'}, 
          {id: 3, name: 'Shop 3'}
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'country', 
        value: 'all', 
        options: [
          {id: 'all', name: 'All countries'}, 
          {id: 1, name: 'Country 1'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Country 2'}, 
          {id: 3, name: 'Country 3'}
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'gender', 
        value: 'all', 
        options: [
          {id: 'all', name: 'All genders'}, 
          {id: 1, name: 'Gender 1'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Gender 2'}, 
          {id: 3, name: 'Gender 3'}
        ]
      }]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    shop() {
      return this.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'shop')[0].value;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    shop() {
      $.when((async function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let newCountries = [];
          for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            newCountries.push({id: rand, name: 'Country: ' + rand});
            let countryObject = vueApp.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'country')[0];
            countryObject.options = [{id: 'all', name: 'All countries'}, ...newCountries];
            countryObject.value = 'all';
          }     
        }, 200);
      })(), (async function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let newGenders = [];
          for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            newGenders.push({id: rand, name: 'Gender: ' + rand});
            let genderObject = vueApp.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'gender')[0];
            genderObject.options = [{id: 'all', name: 'All genders'}, ...newGenders];
            genderObject.value = 'all';
          }     
        }, 100);    
      })());
    },
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      console.log('updating');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div style='list-style-type: none' v-for="input in inputs">
    <p><b>{{ input.name }}</b></p>
    <select v-model="input.value" @change="update">
      <option v-for="option in input.options" :value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you need the `country` and `gender` values to change before calling the `update` method, then add a separate method as a handler for the `change` event to set the new `country` and `gender` values and then call the `update` method after that has finished.

Here's and example of that:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let vueApp = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{
        name: 'shop', 
        value: 'all', 
        options: [
          {id: 'all', name: 'All shops'}, 
          {id: 1, name: 'Shop 1'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Shop 2'}, 
          {id: 3, name: 'Shop 3'}
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'country', 
        value: 'all', 
        options: [
          {id: 'all', name: 'All countries'}, 
          {id: 1, name: 'Country 1'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Country 2'}, 
          {id: 3, name: 'Country 3'}
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'gender', 
        value: 'all', 
        options: [
          {id: 'all', name: 'All genders'}, 
          {id: 1, name: 'Gender 1'}, 
          {id: 2, name: 'Gender 2'}, 
          {id: 3, name: 'Gender 3'}
        ]
      }]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    shop() {
      return this.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'shop')[0].value;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(name) {
      if (name === 'shop') {
        $.when((async function() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            let newCountries = [];
            for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
              let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
              newCountries.push({id: rand, name: 'Country: ' + rand});
              let countryObject = vueApp.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'country')[0];
              countryObject.options = [{id: 'all', name: 'All countries'}, ...newCountries];
              countryObject.value = 'all';
            }     
          }, 200);
        })(), (async function() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            let newGenders = [];
            for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
              let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
              newGenders.push({id: rand, name: 'Gender: ' + rand});
              let genderObject = vueApp.inputs.filter(d => d.name === 'gender')[0];
              genderObject.options = [{id: 'all', name: 'All genders'}, ...newGenders];
              genderObject.value = 'all';
            }     
          }, 100);    
        })()).then(this.update);
      } else {
        this.update()
      }
    },
    update() {
      console.log('updating');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div style='list-style-type: none' v-for="input in inputs">
    <p><b>{{ input.name }}</b></p>
    <select v-model="input.value" @change="onChange(input.name)">
      <option v-for="option in input.options" :value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It certainly tales care of the multiple update calls problem but now the update is called before any changes have been made to the country and gender value. So if I change shop I need to reset the other inputs to 'all' before I call update (or in the ideal case keep the old value if it remains in the updated input list).

Comment: @K.Nordqvist if that's the case, then you should simply put all of the logic to change the country and gender values in a separate handler method for the change event and wait for those to finish before calling the `update` methods. (see my edit)